# How to split a View in several pages when a number of elements is reached?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views

I am using Views to display a gallery. Right now I have set up the View so it onlys shows 50 elements, but I want it to display a "Next" button that takes you to the next batch of elements. Preferably using AJAX / without reloading, but its not necessary.

How can I do this? I have looked at all the options and searched for a module that does that with no success, but I am sure its a standard funcionality and you people can help me.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right in views. Tell it to use a pager, and how many per page. That will split the results into X per page and you can still use the AJAX with it.

If you are talking about grouping, like show all set A, then next to set B, you could try grouping by a primary identifier and see if that groups per page. That is also part of Views.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt see that option somehow... Anyway, if i mark use ajax, when i click on a page number, it gives me an "an error occurred at views/ajax" message? 

Any clues? I am using ninesixty as my based theme, if its any help

Comment: Not sure if AJAX works with the views preview or not, if thats what you mean.

Comment: No, I meant in the final page of this view.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I haven't used the AJAX option before personally.